# C++ Destroying Variables via Scoping

Tags: c++, lifetime-scoping

Is it safe or acceptable practice to create 'temporary' objects in C++ with an empty scope (such as the following), in order to ensure they are immediately destroyed?

```
{
    SingularPurpose singular(&ptr_to_something);
}
```

Comment: Note: While this code is an okay way to create and immediately destroy something, *the fact that that's a useful thing to do* is a code smell. In a well-designed program, this code wouldn't do anything useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly acceptable practice and can be very useful for more than just individual objects. For example locking shared resources while some operations are performed and unlocking it automatically when it goes out of scope:

```
// normal program stuff here ...

// introduce an open scope
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // lock a resource in this scope

    // do stuff with the resource ...

    // at the end of the scope the lock object is destroyed
    // and the resource becomes available to other threads    
}

// normal program stuff continues ...
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Your scope isn't empty. It contains the declaration of `singular`.
2. That's perfectly OK, but...
3. ...there's no need to create a variable; you can just create a temporary object (which is not a variable):

   ```
   SingularPurpose(&ptr_to_something);
   ```